# Can I set the default search directory on fzf?

Tags: plugin-fzf

I set the following on my `~/.vimrc` which sets the current directory to the location of the file on the buffer.

```
au BufEnter * silent! :lcd%:p:h
```

However, when I run the fzf command to search for a file, then the search starts on the current directory, althogh the file I like to get is often in other directories. So I want to set it to `~/` whenever I run fzf.

But I'm not sure if it is possible. Is it possible to set it in fzf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following info can be found in the [official docs](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/doc/fzf.txt) of fzf:

You can execute `:FZF` with an argument for the starting dir. So you can just run `:FZF ~` instead of `:FZF`.  If you open the fzf buffer from a mapping just change that mapping:

```
map <c-space> :FZF ~<cr>
```

(Unrelated to the question but related to the autocomand you mentioned: [`'autochdir'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'autochdir'))

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a default path to fzf if you configure it to use [fd](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) (or [rigrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) or [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher)) in your .bashrc.

Then calling fzf from vim will also use this path as a starting point.

My .bashrc has the following line so all searches being from my home directory:

```
export FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND="fd . $HOME"
```

(note that on Debian Buster, the command would be "fdfind . $HOME)

I found that this produced too many results, so I implemented a solution to have a subset of the directories in $HOME searched (see a blog post about it [here](https://matt-a-bennett.github.io/fzf_search_dirs/fzf_search_dirs.html))